# How to config Druid indexing slots capacity?

Tags: indexing, druid

By default there are 2 indexing slots capacity when run druid in standalone machine.

If you have more than 2 kafka datasources to index, there are always 2 running tasks and remains are in pending tasks status.

My question is how to enlarge druid indexing slots capacity so that it can run more tasks in parallel? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the number of tasks by updating below property in middlemanager runtime.properties.

```
# Number of tasks per middleManager 
druid.worker.capacity=2
```

But keep in mind accordingly you need to update the system resource allocation too eg. if your system has only 2 processors than it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I noticed that there are many pending tasks while only one running task after enlarge "druid.worker.capacity", why and how to make them running?

Comment: On the Coordinator Console what do you see under Remote workers, druid worker capacity?